# Why does PhantomJS return integers when using the getBBox() method?

Tags: javascript, svg, phantomjs

I'm using PhantomJS 1.9.7 and a modified version of [this](http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111018/tree.html) D3.js tree sample, but need to do some different calculations with the labels that involve using their bounding box. When I call `getBBox()` on the `text` DOM element the values I receive are all integers, not floats.

I've put together an example which showcases this:

[Look at the following result in your browser](http://jsfiddle.net/99mAZ/2/), then run this with PhantomJS and observe the console output:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();

page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg, lineNum, sourceId) {
    console.log(msg);
};

page.onAlert = function() {
    phantom.exit();
};

page.open('http://jsfiddle.net/99mAZ/4/');
```

For me, the output (truncated) is like so with Chrome:

```
{"x":10,"y":-6.40625,"width":60,"height":13.015625}
{"x":-49,"y":-6.40625,"width":39,"height":13.015625}
{"x":-41,"y":-6.40625,"width":31,"height":13.015625}
{"x":-39,"y":-6.40625,"width":29,"height":13.015625}
{"x":-29,"y":-6.40625,"width":19,"height":13.015625}
```

And with Phantom:

```
{"x":10,"y":-7,"width":60,"height":13}
{"x":-49,"y":-7,"width":39,"height":13}
{"x":-41,"y":-7,"width":31,"height":13}
{"x":-39,"y":-7,"width":29,"height":13}
```

`getBBox()` returns an SVGRect. The [interface](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/types.html#InterfaceSVGRect) for an SVGRect is defined to return all float values. They could very well be floats, but they're at the very least *rounded*, which isn't of much use when working with larger units such as inches.

Is there any way to get more precision?

Comment: Have you tested in other browsers? It may just be that Chrome has subpixel rendering, and Phantom only calculates positioning to the whole-pixel level. Not sure what IE10/11 or Firefox support.

Comment: @loganfsmyth Safari I thought had the same output as Chrome, but I guess I didn't do an accurate enough quick scan. All three report slightly different numbers. [Here's a gist](https://gist.github.com/landr0id/213ced80c2193fbda0b2) of those.

Comment: Firefox and IE have returned floating point values for getBBox for as long as they've supported SVG.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most browsers, until the last year or two, have had very little concept of positioning below whole-pixel resolution. Since it is so new, it will be hard to get full consistency of these values across multiple browsers.

The version of PhantomJS that you are using probably doesn't support sub-pixel positioning. I'm not sure if that's because you have an older version or it is simply isn't supported.

Comment: I'm using the latest version, so maybe they haven't updated the webkit backend. I'm going to hold off before marking this as the answer, but this is a sufficient answer that explains why numbers are rounded up.

Comment: That's true for html but not really for SVG for which any reasonable implementation must really support floats to allow for scaling/zooming.

Comment: @RobertLongson I'm not sure how these interface definitions work, but [the SVGRect.idl](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/src/qt/src/3rdparty/webkit/Source/WebCore/svg/SVGRect.idl) declares them as floats. I traced some getBBox() methods back to [here](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/4989445e714bb97fe49ef8c00ccbce8b6cfbfbb0/src/qt/src/3rdparty/webkit/Source/WebCore/rendering/svg/SVGRenderSupport.cpp#L163), but don't have the time right now to fully trace it back to see how it populates the struct.

Comment: Current Webkit version on PhantomJS is 534.34, released on 2011 (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/phantomjs/vDJAoEllTO8) the fix for subpixel rendering was done on 2012 (https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=60318). See this for more information: http://bricss.net/post/22718920352/subpixel-layout-coming-to-webkit